# C# XML De serialization and arrays

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-deserialization

There is next xml file:

```
<element Name="root">
    <SubFields>
        <element Name="subroot">
            <SubFields>
                <element1 Name="element1" customatt1 = "12313" customatt2 = "asdfasfadsfasd">
                    <subelement Name="subelement" />
                </element1>
                <element1 Name="element11" customatt1 = "12313" customatt2 = "asdfasfadsfasd">
                    <subelement Name="subelement" />
                </element1>
                <element1 Name="element111" customatt1 = "12313" customatt2 = "asdfasfadsfasd">
                    <subelement Name="subelement" />
                </element1>
                <element2 Name="element2" path = "asdfdsf" widget="asdasdasd">
                    <subelement Name="subelement" />
                </element2>
                <element2 Name="element22" path = "asdfdsf" widget="asdasdasd">
                    <subelement Name="subelement" />
                </element2>
                <element2 Name="element222" path = "asdfdsf" widget="asdasdasd">
                    <subelement Name="subelement" />
                </element2>
            </SubFields>
        </element>
    </SubFields>
</element>
```

I mapped  the array of elements as `[XmlArray("SubFields")]` where SubFields is root of arrays and Question:
 How to map differences types of elements in object ?
And I can have a lot of `subroot` -s elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [XMLSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class. Near the bottom theres a section about using Property attributes to map the object to the xml elements

Comment: The main idea of question how to map differences element in xml sequence in object, and under "map" I understood use of c# attributes like [XMLArray] and so on.

Comment: Do you need the XMl in that exact format? If not it's usually a lot easier to create and populate the object that you can then serialize and deserialize to xml rather than the other way round.

Comment: I need a object that will be contain all data from this xml file namely: 
 - arrays of element
 - arrays of element1
 - arrays of element2
That is all.

Comment: Have you got an object written already to deserialize the xml into?

Comment: I need to write this object, I have written objects only for top part of xml: <element Name="root">
    <SubFields>
        <element Name="subroot">
         </element>
    </SubFields>
 </element>
Currently I need to write for the another elements .